# REST callout's output is not correct (a string is not a string)?

Tags: apex, callout, trailhead

I am trying to do [the Apex REST Callout Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts).

One of the challenge requirements is:

> The 'getAnimalNameById' method must call `https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/:id`, using the ID passed into the method. The method returns the value of the 'name' property (i.e., the animal name).

However I'm getting this error : [image: a string is not a string??]

The returned string is not a string?

Here is the code doing the deserializing :

```
map<String, Object> results = (map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
list<Object> animals = (list<Object>)results.get('animals');
returnedString = (string)JSON.serialize(animals.get(id-1));
```

Here is the test class that asserts :

```
AnimalLocator ANML = new AnimalLocator();
Test.SetMock(HttpCallOutMock.class, new AnimalLocatorMock());
string result = ANML.getAnimalNameById(3);

string expectedResult = 'scary bear';

System.assertEquals(result, 'scary bear');
System.assertEquals(result, expectedResult);
```

And here is the mock callout class that sets the body of the request (I do not know precisely how it works, I picked it up from developer forums) :

```
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.setBody('{"animals": ["majestic badger", "fluffy bunny", "scary bear", "chicken"]}');
```

Please refer to `https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/` for the JSON source.

Comment: Likely to be that you have got double quotes actually in the string. Run this `System.assertEquals('"abc"', 'abc');` and you will get that sort of failure message.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question.

Comment: Even if someone has the full answer to your problem, I hope they would not post it here as Trailhead progress is mean to be through your own understanding and work.

Comment: But I donot know why my code is not working... can I not ask for help? Surely there may be SOME cases where I could have made a mistake but I'm unable (perhaps due to limited knowledge) to see the problem?

Comment: With more code posted yes asking is maybe more appropriate. First thing to say is that you have the expected and actual values reversed in `System.assertEquals(result, 'scary bear');` which makes the assertion failure message misleading. My hint to you of the cause of the problem is that you would generally only ever serialize or deserialize in a method and you should learn about [casting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm).

Comment: OK, I changed it around, as you suggested and the code is working fine. 100% test coverage too... but the trailhead is not accepting it as the answer :( I need to look deeper

Comment: Found out the problem : method was not static. Changed it and how it was called in testclass and I have passed the trailhead. Thanks for showing me something new today :)

Comment: Nice work figuring it all out - best way to learn.

Comment: @fraglord you should post that as answer, complete with the modified code, to help any others who may have the same issue, and to remove this question from the unanswered list.